# Issue with Groupby.apply on multindex dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby

I have a multiindex dataframe (index has 2 levels) and my variables as columns.

I'm trying to apply a function for each 1st level index. The idea is just to do a rolling standardization on the data itself:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import robust_scale, power_transform

df[list_feat_num] = df[list_feat_num].groupby(level='date').apply(lambda x: power_transform(x))
```

and obtained the folowing error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

**Reproducing example**:

```
import numpy as np

iterable = [[1,2,3,4],['a','b','d','e','f','g','h']]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterable, names=['date', 'sub'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(28, 4), index =idx, columns=['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'])


df[['var1', 'var2']] = df[['var1', 'var2']].groupby(level='date').apply(lambda x: power_transform(x, method='yeo-johnson' ))
```

After investigating, the function is correctly applied, but everything is return back into a Serie, instead back to a multindex dataframe. Thus the error, as it cannot assign back to the original dataframe.

What can I do ? Is it related to the broadcast argument ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: ok, I'm updating my post

Comment: updated with reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

For me working add DataFrame constructor in lambda function with set index values of groups:

```
np.random.seed(123)
from sklearn.preprocessing import robust_scale, power_transform
import numpy as np

iterable = [[1,2,3,4],['a','b','d','e','f','g','h']]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterable, names=['date', 'sub'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(28, 4), index =idx, columns=['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'])
```

---

```
f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame(power_transform(x, method='yeo-johnson'), index=x.index)
df[['var1', 'var2']] = df.groupby(level='date')['var1', 'var2'].apply(f)
```

Your solution:

```
df[['var1', 'var2']] = df[['var1', 'var2']].groupby(level='date').apply(f)
```

---

```
print (df)
              var1      var2      var3      var4
date sub                                        
1    a   -1.175573  0.381748  0.282978 -1.506295
     b   -0.764622  0.894719 -2.426679 -0.428913
     d    0.691332 -1.262392 -0.678886 -0.094709
     e    0.865815 -1.043243 -0.443982 -0.434351
     f    1.415725  1.300722  1.004054  0.386186
     g    0.280003  0.770592 -0.935834  1.175829
     h   -1.312680 -1.042147  0.907105 -1.428681
2    a   -0.206304 -0.500801 -0.255619 -2.798589
     b   -1.666581 -0.310982  0.927462 -0.173636
     d   -0.072625  0.877042 -0.879536  0.283627
     e   -0.813829 -1.675651 -0.390900  0.573806
     f    0.246787  0.375910  2.392365  0.412912
     g    0.872225  1.659402 -1.294085 -1.038788
     h    1.640327 -0.424921  0.029683  1.069316
3    a    0.479722  1.617368  1.495644  1.069393
     b   -1.115289  0.643884  0.314272 -1.326265
     d    1.140015  0.656820  0.045490 -0.233092
     e   -1.420566  0.005083  0.468439 -0.831155
     f    0.812374 -1.532627 -2.123100  1.039727
     g   -0.826485 -0.361822 -0.837517 -1.605963
     h    0.930229 -1.028705  1.660952  0.807308
4    a   -0.603502 -0.331612 -0.732462 -1.212523
     b    1.777348  0.858457  1.150206 -1.267352
     d    0.016055  1.603220 -0.335011  1.031114
     e   -1.756332 -0.633755  0.379401 -0.379176
     f    0.508385 -1.340540  0.712265  2.598304
     g   -0.227608  0.750350  0.179549 -1.861976
     h    0.285653 -0.906120 -0.427680  1.242870
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whats the intuition for passing the columns after the groupby and not before ?

Comment: @lucaschn - It is more common way for pass columns for processing in some function after `groupby` in pandas ;)